# Javascript Date creation difference - in IE vs chrome

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, date, internet-explorer

I am getting a long from the backend system that represents a date.
 I convert the long to javascript Date by using - new Date(long).

I get different dates for the same long in IE and Chrome.
 The correct date is the one shown in Chrome.

[example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cJG5H.jpg)

For example:
 `new Date(1032382800000)`

In **IE** the date value is - Wed Sep 18 2002 23:00:00 GMT **+0200**.
 In **Chrome** date value is - Thu Sep 19 2002 00:00:00 GMT **+0300**.

How can I solve this discrepancy?

Comment: These are both the same date. The time zone is just different - it's +3 in one case and +2 in the other. Since the time zone is an hour apart, taking one hour off midnight rolls the date back a day. But it's still the exact same UTC time in both cases.

Comment: But the user sees two different dates.

Comment: I guess one question is why is IE in a different time zone than Chrome. Other than that, you can treat this as a UTC date, so the date would not rely on the local time zone. But I'm not sure if that's really what you need or not.

Comment: the UTC date is the wrong date in my case

Comment: In that case, the question is why are you sending the wrong date as a Unix timestamp? Timestamps are *always* in UTC.

Comment: My backend in SAP. I get a java date object from a RFC (Remote Function Call) which i then convert to a long using getTime method.

Comment: Whether the IE browser and Chrome browser on the same machine? I have checked your code on my machine (using Chrome browser and IE Browser), the result is same (using the same time zone). If you are using the browsers on the same machine, perhaps the issue is related to the browser, try to clear the browser data (cache, cookie and so on), then recheck it. Also, you could reset the Browser setting. If you are using different machines and using different time zone, I think it is better to use the UTC time.

Comment: The result is on the same machine and for the same user.
We also tried clearing the cache in both browsers.
The data has also been tested on several machines - still the same.

Comment: It is very strange, the test result looks [like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oNFs8.png). Please check your JavaScript script, whether the date is changed by other script or not? Besides, can you post the Enough code to reproduce the problem as in [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: What timezone is the system set for? This looks like a daylight saving error, where one implementation is using DST up to and including midnight and changing to standard time 1 ms after midnight. The other is changing to standard time at exactly midnight. Try adding 1 ms to the time value and see if both offsets are +2 and the time 23:00:00.001. I don't know of a place that changes at midnight at the start of Thursday, there are a number of Islamic countries that start on Friday though.

Comment: I have added an example in the question.
There is a DST difference between the browsers.

Comment: As RobG said, try to check/change the system time zone. And you could also try to reinstall the IE browser to check whether it could solve the problem. If they all not working, according to the code in your workaround, it seems that you are using two time zones in your code, when using the `(new Date()).getTimezoneOffset()` script, it will use the right time zone. You could consider comparing the time zone offset and use it as a workaround.

Answer (score -1):

I have found a workaround.
Because the time is not relevant in those date objects, I run the following code:

```
       var iTimezoneOffset = dDate.getTimezoneOffset() - (new Date()).getTimezoneOffset();
       if (iTimezoneOffset != 0) {
            dDate.setMinutes(dDate.getMinutes() + iTimezoneOffset);
       }
```

Comment: The only reason that two Date instances should have a different timezone offset is if the host system is configured to observe daylight saving and the dates are on either side of a daylight saving boundary. That this "works" is just chance.

Comment: So what do you suggest I do?